Reversed effective force and d'Alembert's Principle
Reading some answers on this forum on "reversed effective force" and from my class lectures I came to the conclusion that the reversed effective force is just the pseudo force from the rest frame of the object itself. So from this particular frame we have
$$\vec {F} -\dot{\vec p}=\vec 0$$
Now in Goldstein's Classical Mechanics book he uses this frame and says that this particle can be considered to be in equilibrium. And thus the virtual work will be zero.
But then he claims that if this particle was one among a system of $N$ particles then we can write
$$\sum_i ({\vec {F}_i}-\dot{\vec{p}}_i)\cdot 
 \vec{\delta{r_i}}=0$$
This means that "each particle of this system must satisfy the first equation i.e. each of them must be in equilibrium" but my question is that does such a frame even exists from which all of the particles of the system are in their individual rest frame (since from any inertial frame, each particle has different acceleration) ?
If not then how can we use the second equation to build upon the Lagrange equation of motion which the book does?

There is a formal way of representing n identical particles at an instant t as a single particle at different instants: let $(x_{i},t_{i})$ be the positions over time of a single particle. Instead of considering points representing the states of a single particle at different instants $t_{1},t_{2},...$ different, we can all formally consider a very large number (in the limit, an infinite number) of identically* arranged particles which, at a given instant (let's say $t=0$), are in the states represented by the points $x_{1},x_{2},...$
 * such a set is referred to as a “statistical set”.


it's like we record the movement of a single particle on photos (old cinema) and we project the photos (or short film) by superopposing them, we will see n particles.

@TheTiler but we don't need them to be identical !

@Antik : Sorry I have trouble opening my recent messages box (it disappears as soon as it opens), and even worse to write ...(I write first in Textmaker...), it is to simplify...

Following D'Alembert approach to classical mechanics, every particle is in equilibrium under "real" force $\mathbf{F}_i$ and the "fictitious force" $\mathbf{F}_i^f := - \dot{\mathbf{Q}}_i$. For a system of $N$ particles you get $N$ dynamical equations
$$\mathbf{F}_i - \dot{\mathbf{Q}}_i = \mathbf{0} \qquad , \qquad i = 1:N$$
Now, you can multiply each one of this equation for an arbitrary vector $\mathbf{w}_i$, $i=1:N$, and write the previous system of $N$ equation in "weak form",
$$\sum_i \mathbf{w}_i \cdot (\mathbf{F}_i - \dot{\mathbf{Q}}_i) = 0 \qquad , \qquad \forall \mathbf{w}_i \ .$$
From the weak form, you can derive Lagrange equations with a smart choice of the arbitrary vectors $\mathbf{w}_i$. If you describe the position of the points with the generalized coordinates $q_k(t)$,
$$\mathbf{r}_i(q^k(t),t)$$
the velocity becomes
$$\mathbf{v}_i(\dot{q}^k(t), q^k(t), t) = \dfrac{d}{dt} \mathbf{r}_i(q^k(t),t) = \dfrac{\partial \mathbf{r}_i}{\partial q^k} \dot{q}^k + \frac{\partial \mathbf{r}_i}{\partial t} \ .$$
The smart choice leading to Lagrange equations reads $$\mathbf{w}_{i,k} = \frac{\partial \mathbf{r}_i}{\partial q^k} = \frac{\partial \mathbf{v}_i}{\partial \dot{q}^k} \ ,$$
for every generalized variable $q^k$, $k = 1:N_{q}$. With this choice,
$$\sum_i \mathbf{w}_{i,k} \cdot \mathbf{F}_i = - \sum_i \frac{\partial \mathbf{r}_i}{\partial q^k} \cdot \nabla_{\mathbf{r}_i}V = - \dfrac{\partial V}{\partial q^k}$$
$$\sum_i \mathbf{w}_{i,k} \cdot \dot{\mathbf{Q}}_i = \dots = \dfrac{d}{dt}\left( \dfrac{\partial K}{\partial \dot{q}^k} \right) - \left( \dfrac{\partial K}{\partial {q}^k} \right) \ ,$$
and putting everything together, remembering that $\mathscr{L} = T - V$, and $V$ is not a function of $\dot{q}^k$, you get Lagrangian equations for the conservative system
$$\dfrac{d}{dt}\left( \dfrac{\partial \mathscr{L}}{\partial \dot{q}^k} \right) - \left( \dfrac{\partial \mathscr{L}}{\partial {q}^k} \right) = 0 \qquad , \qquad k = 1: N_q \ .$$

I didn't ask for the derivation, I already have it. My question is about the frame of reference we are using to derive this complete relation. Please go through it again if possible.

The inertial reference frame you use to measure velocity and where you can write dynamical equations as $\dot{\mathbf{Q}} = \mathbf{F}^{ext}$
